# Error : Non-numeric argument to mathematical function in R

Tags: r, distribution, poisson

```
dbl_var<-lambda
probpois <-function(x,  lambda){

  #e<-2.718
prob<-exp(((lambda^x)*(2.718^lambda))/factorial(x))

retun(prob)

}

a<-readline((prompt="Enter a value: "))
b<-readline((prompt="Enter b value: "))
lambda<-readline((prompt="Enter lambda value: "))
x<-(a:b)
while (x<b || x>a ) {

dpois(x ,lambda)

}
```

ı want to write calculate poisson distribution program in  R studio. This program will an error. >>
 **"Error in dpois(x, lambda) : Non-numeric argument to mathematical function"**

Console:

```
  > dbl_var<-lambda
> probpois <-function(x,  lambda){
+   
+       #e<-2.718
+  prob<-exp(((lambda^x)*(2.718^lambda))/factorial(x))
+   
+   retun(prob)
+ 
+ 
+ 
+ }
> a<-readline((prompt="Enter a value: "))
Enter a value: 1
> b<-readline((prompt="Enter b value: "))
Enter b value: 4
> lambda<-readline((prompt="Enter lambda value: "))
Enter lambda value: 1.5
> x<-(a:b)
> while (x<b || x>a ) {
+ 
+ dpois(x ,lambda)
+   
+ }
Error in dpois(x, lambda) : Non-numeric argument to mathematical function
>
```

Comment: Using two parentheses in your `readline` calls is a bad idea:  it will create a variable called `prompt` and then pass its value to `readline`.  You should write it as `readline(prompt="Enter a value: ")` if you want to set the argument named `prompt` without creating a new variable.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`readline` always returns whatever the user types as character data. Wrap your `readline` statements in `as.numeric`, like so:

```
a <- as.numeric(readline(prompt="Enter a value: "))
```

In addition, I'm not entirely sure of your goal here, but the `while` loop is being used incorrectly. In fact it seems entirely unnecessary, since `dpois` can simply be given the four values you've calculated for `x`.

Comment: See my comment above about using two levels of parens.